# How do I find the vertex id if we have the vertex object in python Igraph v1.7?

Tags: igraph

```
a=g.vs(Name_eq="A")
b=g.vs(Name_eq="B")
```

I want to add an edge between a and b, how do I go about?

Comment: The question title is wrong; python-igraph does not have a version 1.7.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can find the vertex id by accessing a particular vertex of the vertexSeq as 'a' is a vertex sequence object.

Something like this, should do the trick.

```
a[0].index
```

Answer (score 16):

Okay, it seems like we have two questions here. One is in the question title: "how do I find the vertex ID if we have the Vertex object"? This is correctly [answered by Siddharth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17019896/156771): you can simply use the `index` property of the vertex. The other question is in the question body: "I want to add an edge between a and b, how do I go about?". The answer is simply to use the `add_edge` method which accepts Vertex objects as well as vertex IDs:

```
g.add_edge(a, b)
```

Here I assumed that `a` and `b` are objects of type `Vertex`. However, judging from your code snippet, what  you essentially want to do is to add an edge between two vertices for which you know the names. This can also be done using the `find` method of `VertexSeq` objects, which works like the selection you do but returns only the *first* matching vertex. So, you can simply do:

```
g.add_edge(g.vs.find(Name="A"), g.vs.find(Name="B"))
```

Even better, if you use the `name` vertex attribute to store the vertex names (and not `Name` - note the capital letter), you can even use the name itself without invoking `g.vs.find` since igraph treats the `name` vertex attribute specially:

```
g.add_edge("A", "B")
```

Comment: I just tried it since a is a sequence I had to use a[0] instead of a, ie add_edge(a[0],b[0]), Thanks!